# Erro de data no Pandas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, data, datetime

Estou usando o Pandas para ler uma planilha gigantesca em formato .xlsb para depois tratar os campos e gerar um gráfico.
Infelizmente, o campo de data vem no formato float64 e quando faço a conversão para data, ele coloca todos os dias como sendo 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000044564 e dtype('<M8[ns]').
Na planilha, as datas estão corretas.

P. S.: Estou usando o Python 3 no Anaconda.

Comment: O ideal seria ter na pergunta uma amostra dos dados que esta tentando tabalhar. Também inclua um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel)

Answer (score -1):

Sem acesso aos dados fica difícil resolver. Mas tive um problema parecido com dados de Nascidos Vivos do Datasus. Nesse caso, as datas vieram como int, na forma 15052019. Ao converter diretamente, gerava todas datas iguais com o ano de 1974.

O que fiz foi gerar uma função, convertendo a coluna para string e apliquei o datetime.date() para separar ano, mês e dia. Em seguida usei o map() para aplicar em toda a coluna de datas df['DTNASC']. Pode ser que o código abaixo lhe dê uma luz na solução.

```
def get_datetime(data):
    date_string = str(data)
    return datetime.date(int(date_string[-4:]), 
                         int(date_string[-6:-4]), 
                         int(date_string[-8:-6]))

df['DTNASC'] = df.DTNASC.map(get_datetime)
df['DTNASC'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DTNASC)
```

Comment: Essa orientação está equivocada. A solução para o problema se dá na leitura do arquivo manipulando os argumentos `date_parser` e `parse_dates` das funções de leitura `pandas.read_csv()`, `pandas.read_excel()` , `pandas.read_clipboard()` ou `pandas.read_table()`

Comment: Interessante. Na quebrei um pouco a cabeça e irei também rever meu arquivo com essas orientações.

Comment: Se precisar de ajuda "estamos" aqui.